# How to build a Seurat container?

Tags: r, docker, seurat

I'm trying to analyze single-cell RNAseq data by Seurat.

Recently I encountered Docker ecosystem seemingly very reproducible. I tried three manners, but all failed. Do you have any idea or good information??

**Enviroment:**

- PC: Surface Laptop2
- OS: Windows10 + WSL2
- Docker: Docker desktop for Windows
- DockerImages: [rocker/rstudio](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse), [satijalab/seurat](https://hub.docker.com/r/satijalab/seurat)

## 1. Build rocker/tidyverse container installing Seurat package by installer2.r command.

This is a Dockerfile.

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse
RUN apt update

# install Seurat package via a install2.r liner
RUN install2.r Seurat --error --deps TRUE --skipinstalled --ncpus -1
```

This is a Docker-compse file.

```
version: '3'
services: 
  rocker: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: rocker
    hostname: rocker
    ports:
      - '8787:8787'
    environment:
      - PASSWORD=pass
```

But

```
Docker-compose up --build
```

returns errors. In summary, "installation of one or more packages failed, probably ‘Cairo’, ‘mutoss’, ‘ggrastr’, ‘metap’."

## 2. Build Seurat container installing RStudio-server.

This is a Dockerfile.

```
FROM satijalab/seurat:latest
RUN apt update

# install prerequisites
RUN apt install -y \
  ca-certificates \
  libssl-dev \ 
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  libssh2-1-dev

# install rstudio-server for Ubntu20
RUN wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/debian9/x86_64/rstudio-server-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
RUN apt install -y ./rstudio-server-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
RUN rm rstudio-server-2021.09.2-382-amd64.deb
```

This is a Docker-compse file.

```
version: '3'
services: 
  seurat: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  container_name: seurat
  hostname: seurat
  ports:
    - '0.0.0.0:8787:8787'
  environment:
    - PASSWORD=pass
  tty: true
  stdin_open: true
```

It created a container successfully. Then I accessed "http://localhost:8787/", it returned "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE." I suspected that rstudio-server didn't run.

```
docker exec  -it  seurat bash
```

Then

```
rstudio-server start
```

It returned "/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."

It seemed that libssl package version error occured. I changed docker-compse file from,

```
RUN apt install -y libssl-dev
```

to,

```
RUN apt install -y libssl1.0.2
```

but it returned no package found error.

## 3. Build rocker/tidyverse container. Log in to RStudio-server. install.packages("Seurat").

Simply I could build and log-in to a rocker/tidyverse container by accessing to localhost:8787.

Then I tried to install Seurat package by

```
install.packages("Seurat")
```

At first glance it seemed install was successfully done. But

```
library(Seurat)
```

returned,

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/rstudio/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
  libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Satija Lab already builds [Docker containers with Rocker+Seurat](https://hub.docker.com/r/satijalab/seurat), so if you are only learning Docker, it would be better to use their images. Otherwise, [their Dockerfiles are available on GitHub](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat-docker/blob/master/latest/Dockerfile).

Comment: Thanks to your reply! 

As you mentioned, I first simply build Rocker + Seurat container from Satija Lab's official image. But accessing to the port (localhost:8787) returned "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE."

I did "docker exec" and inspected weather RStudio-server was running. But it seemed no running. So I re-installed RStudio server.

Comment: Recently I successfully built the desired container. I used Bioconductor R image for base image. After logging into container, install.packages() ran correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @ToshiK yes, they use `rocker/r-ver` as their base image, which does not include RStudio.